# Delete from source using MERGE command in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a temp table data in @temptable I need  to compare this data with table name  LU_BCOMS_UsersRepFamilies

by using this @temptable data I need to replace in Master table LU_BCOMS_UsersRepFamilies based on where condition with the following columns

```
1) RepFamily_RepFamilyId 
2) Users_UserId
```

My Query Listed Below :

```
declare @tempTable 
Table(RepFamily_RepFamilyId int,Users_UserId varchar(500),CreatedDate varchar(500),CreatedBy varchar(500))
insert into @tempTable values('676','MV10310','2014-05-20 13:30:29.000','MV10310')

MERGE INTO LU_BCOMS_UsersRepFamilies AS target
USING @tempTable AS source
    ON target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId
    AND target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
    target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId,
    target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId,
    target.CreatedDate = source.CreatedDate,
    target.CreatedBy = source.CreatedBy
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (RepFamily_RepFamilyId, Users_UserId, CreatedDate,CreatedBy)
    VALUES (source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId, source.Users_UserId, source.CreatedDate,source.CreatedBy)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE  THEN
    DELETE  WHERE target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId and target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId;
```

After execute my query I am getting the following error

Error : 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

can you modify my query according the requirement specified above

```
Example : 

    RepFamily_RepFamilyId  Users_UserId  CreatedDate  CreatedBy
    600                         MV10310     date           ravi
    601                         MV10310     date           ravi
    602                         KV110       date           suma
    603                         GV122       date           rajesh

in my temp table I have 

    insert into @tempTable values('600','MV10310','date','ravi')

after merging my master table show look like below :

     RepFamily_RepFamilyId  Users_UserId  CreatedDate  CreatedBy
        600                         MV10310     date           ravi   
        602                         KV110       date           suma
        603                         GV122       date           rajesh
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` goes in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` line...

Example:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND SOMEVALUE=5 THEN
DELETE;
```

However.... in your code above, your `WHERE` of:

```
WHERE target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId and target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId
```

Is the same as your `USING-ON` of:

```
ON target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId
    AND target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId
```

So if it's `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` (missing from source) your where condition will never be satisfied, and nothing will ever delete...

I believe you just want to remove the WHERE as follows:

```
MERGE INTO LU_BCOMS_UsersRepFamilies AS target
USING @tempTable AS source
    ON target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId
    AND target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
    target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId,
    target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId,
    target.CreatedDate = source.CreatedDate,
    target.CreatedBy = source.CreatedBy
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (RepFamily_RepFamilyId, Users_UserId, CreatedDate,CreatedBy)
    VALUES (source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId, source.Users_UserId, source.CreatedDate,source.CreatedBy)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND target.Users_UserId IN (SELECT DISTINCT Users_UserId FROM @tempTable) THEN 
    DELETE;
```

Comment: if I write as above it deletes all the record I don't want it to happen, it should delete record related to User_UserId.

Comment: Well like I said, you can put conditions in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` but I think your conditions need to be re-written.

Comment: how I need to write the condition in WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE for deleting...by RepFamily_RepFamilyId and Users_UserId

Comment: Can you explain the conditions you require in detail?

Comment: As I already said that it should delete by RepFamily_RepFamilyId and Users_UserId .........WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE

Comment: I'm not understanding.  Please provide examples of what is in LU_BCOMS_UsersRepFamilies before the merge, that isn't after, which you want to remain in LU_BCOMS_UsersRepFamilies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer..

```
MERGE INTO LU_BCOMS_UsersRepFamilies AS target
USING @tempTable AS source
    ON target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId
    AND target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
    target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId,
    target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId,
    target.CreatedDate = source.CreatedDate,
    target.CreatedBy = source.CreatedBy
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (RepFamily_RepFamilyId, Users_UserId, CreatedDate,CreatedBy)
    VALUES (source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId, source.Users_UserId, source.CreatedDate,source.CreatedBy)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND  target.Users_UserId = (select top 1 (A.Users_UserId) from @tempTable as A) Then 
 DELETE ;
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, I just posted update also which will allow more than one `Users_UserId` in `@temptable`.  Yours will only delete a single `Users_UserId`, and leave the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change your Last Delete Statement,

```
DELETE  source WHERE target.RepFamily_RepFamilyId = source.RepFamily_RepFamilyId and target.Users_UserId = source.Users_UserId;
```